# Get sum of left leaves of a binary tree using recursion

Tags: binary-tree, tree-traversal

I have the following code but there seems to be an issue in this code:

```
private boolean isLeaf(TreeNode node) {
    if (node == null)
        return false;
    if (node.left == null && node.right == null)
        return true;
    return false;
}

public int sumOfLeftLeaves(TreeNode root) {
    if (root == null)
        return 0;
    if (isLeaf(root.left))
        return root.left.val;
    return sumOfLeftLeaves(root.left) + sumOfLeftLeaves(root.right);
}
```

For the input `[3, 9, 20, null, null, 15, 7, 2, null, null, null, 3, 2, null, null, null, 3]` I get `9` using the code above but the answer should be `12` i.e. `9 + 3`.

What is missing from this code?

The input array represents a binary tree where if a parent is at position `i` then its left child is at `2 * i + 1` and right child is at `2 * i + 2`.

Comment: It seems root value is not added in sumOfLeftLeaves().

Comment: How are you building the tree? Your expected sum seems incorrect, and then there are possible anomalies in the input data where at least one node seems to be an orphan (the `2` in position 7 has parent `null` in position 3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First problem :

```
[3, 9, 20, null, null, 15, 7, 2, null, null, null, 3, 2, null, null, null, 3]
```

3 is the root, it has 9 and 20 as children.
9 doesn't have any children, 20 has 15 and 7.
Where does the 2 belong?

Here's the tree in Ruby :

```
Node (0) : 3
    Node (2) : 20
        Node (6) : 7
            Node (14) : nil
            Node (13) : nil
        Node (5) : 15
            Node (12) : 2
            Node (11) : 3
    Node (1) : 9
        Node (4) : nil
            Node (10) : nil
            Node (9) : nil
        Node (3) : nil
            Node (8) : nil
            Node (7) : 2
                Node (16) : 3
                Node (15) : nil
```

Second problem :

A node could have a leaf on the left but a branch on the right :

```
public int sumOfLeftLeaves(TreeNode root) {
    if (root == null)
        return 0;
    if (isLeaf(root.left))
        return root.left.val+sumOfLeftLeaves(root.right);
    return sumOfLeftLeaves(root.left) + sumOfLeftLeaves(root.right);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a sum variable that actually adds the node's values.

```
    if(!root)
        return 0;
    
    if(root->left && root->left->left == NULL && root->left->right == NULL) //checking for leaf
        sum += root->left->val;
    
    sum += (sumOfLeftLeaves(root->left) + sumOfLeftLeaves(root->right));
    return sum;
```